# Android custom codec or encrypt media file?

Tags: android

I want to create an application which permits to the user to download media files and play them, but only with my application. So first of all I thought that encrypting files will be a good solution, but it takes to much. Now I'm thinking to create a custom codec for my media files. I didn't work until now with codecs so how complicated is to make one for Android? Can be made in java or only in C and used via JNI? Also can you recomand me some useful books for understanding how are codecs created?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Custom codec would take much more effort than usual encryption. Writing decent(comparable to MPEG4, not x264) codec might take 1000 hours if you already know all underlying technologies.

To understand writing codecs you need to learn DCT and it's optimization, arithmetic/huffman coding. After that you will change your mind for sure :-)

So, go for encription.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your reply. In this case I will try to find a fast method to encrypt and decrypt files.

Comment: @user475480 hi, could you please share your findings in securing media files in android ?